# MultipeerConnectivity MCPeerID displayName error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

When setting up MultipeerConnectivity I'm getting the following error: Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1.

The error is caused when getting the devices display name - any ideas ??

```
 import UIKit
 import MultipeerConnectivity
 import MessageUI
 import AVFoundation

 class Selection: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

  let serviceType = "testApp"
  var browser : MCBrowserViewController!
  var assistant : MCAdvertiserAssistant!
  var session : MCSession!
  var peerID: MCPeerID?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self

    // this line causes the error
    peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name) 
    print("peerID = \(peerID)")

    session = MCSession(peer: self.peerID!, securityIdentity: nil,  encryptionPreference: MCEncryptionPreference.None)
    session = MCSession(peer:peerID!, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: MCEncryptionPreference.None)
    session?.delegate = self
    print("self.peerID = \(self.peerID)")
    self.session = MCSession(peer: peerID!)
    self.session.delegate = self
```

}

Comment: Can you show what error? nil value? did you check this tutorial? http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/

Comment: @UlyssesR - My question does show the error. Ive just downloaded the appcoda sample code you suggested and I'm getting the same error !! It must be the way i've got xCode set up. ?? (Version 7.2.1)

Comment: Thats very odd... can you add an exception breakpoint and see where it crashes? are you testing in an ipod?

Comment: the crash only happens when   peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name) is read. Take this line away and the app runs fine ?? It makes no difference if running on iPod, simulator whatever